# Large Screen for Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Hi all I want to design a widget for Samsung Galaxy S5 and this widget dimension is 4x5 cell. I download the Sony Add-on SDK 3.0 for AVD but find out that it only support 4x4 cell. So my question is there any solution can let me create a 4x5 cell AVD? Thanks.